# Getting access to the message body when handling errors in NServiceBus Version 3

Tags: nservicebus

I'm currently handing off exceptions to a third party telemetry tracking service (Raygun). One of the details I want to include in those exception logs is the actual contents of the message, ideally serialized to JSON.

I'm handling this at the end of the `MessageHandler`. I'm aware that I could also use the `IManageMessageFailures` interface, but then I lose the benefits of the second level retries.

I'm currently doing this:

```
public void End(Exception e)
{
  // get the current message context
  var context = this.Bus.CurrentMessageContext;

  // now where do I get the body of the message from?
  this.ExceptionLogger(new Log(e, context.WhereAreYouMessage.SerializedAsString()));
}
```

This is NSB 3.3. I notice that I can cast the `CurrentMessageContext` to `NServiceBus.Unicast.MessageContext`, but the `TransportMessage` property which contains the message `Body` is private.

How can I get a copy of the message that caused the exception?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported in version 3.

You can look in your error queue which will have the exception details correlated with the message body http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/errors/#configure-your-error-queue